# MDX query complexity

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Need help with querying ssas cube.

For example I have:

1) Dimention table contracts. Table has columns: contract_id, customer_id, customer_type. One customer may have several contracts, contract_id is unique, so for example data could be:

[image]

2) Fact table transactions. Table has columns: transaction_id, contract_id, date, amount. One contract may have several transactions (dimention and fact table ar linked via contract_id), transacion_id is unique. So for example data could be:

[image]

I want to get active (that have transactions) and passive (that don't have transactions) customers count by customer type.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how Company can have active customers with the given sample... I see 2 passive there and 0 active.

Comment: Sorry, bad example. I edited the post.

Comment: what mdx have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way, looking for something more "elegant"

```
with c as (
   select distinct 
            c.customer_type, 
            c.customer_id,
            case when exists (
                            select null 
                            from transactions t 
                            where t.contract_id = c.contract_id
                            --and t.[date] < @parameterx
                            --and t.[date] > @parametery) 
            then 1 else 0 end as contract_exists
from customers c
)
select 
  customer_type,
  sum(case when contract_exists = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when contract_exists = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from c
group by customer_type
```

Comment: Yes. But if we will add parameter transaction date from and transaction date to? Can we get expected result without appending dimention table with additional fields?

Comment: You can add  these parameters in the `where` clause of the `select null from transactions...` part

Comment: But as post title says i want to query from cube with mdx and use that query in ssrs later. You suggest to generate cube with already filtered data?

Comment: Not sure I understand  the logic : you want a query which gives you a result without transaction date (your desired result), and then filter on transaction date ? How could it be possible ?

Comment: Or maybe look at this  : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145518.aspx# ?

Comment: I want to generate cube from all data. User will specify transaction date from/to in ssrs report. So I can't have column is_active in table contracts.

Comment: I know how to parametrize the query I just can't figure out how to write such query to get expected result..

Comment: this answer is sql - the question is in connection with mdx?